# Hide console when opening WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, console

[image]I am trying to write a WinForm directly from Notepad++

But when I run the .exe file it opens a console with no text and also the WinForm
If I close it the WinForm closes

How can I hide the console so only the WinForm opens
My base code is:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CodeTry
{
    public class Form1336 : Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1336());        
        }

        public Form1336()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(500, 300);
            this.Location = new Point(30, 30);
        }               
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Note: When I double-click on try.exe, the console Window opens (the one in black) and also de WinForm. If I close the console the WinForm closes

Comment: This is really hard to understand, perhaps a screenshot would help

Comment: Well it sounds like when you compiled from the command line you are specifying that the app is a **console app** instead of a **Windows Application**

Comment: @MickyD thanks, that sounds like it can be the issue. Also I was taking a look to the files that are automatically written in VS2013 for a WinForm on the file.cs and file.designer.cs but I cannot find which line configures the console to hide or to, as you said, specify is a Windows Application

Comment: I guess it would be the command line when you compile.  I have no experience there sadly.  I needs my IDEs ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compile using:

`/target:winexe` command line switch

This will give you a UI Windows Executable.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-winexe-compiler-option)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Visual Studio; under application in the project properties window, change the output type from Console Application to Windows Application.

[image: Project properties window]

Comment: Additionally check if in the `<PropertyGroup>`  of your `*.csproj` file  you have `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`, in my case that did the trick (was `Exe` instead of `WinExe` before).